# why am i getting the cannot send session cookie error on my php webpage when it is in an online webserver?

Tags: php, session, cookies, send, wampserver

i have a perfectly working site in my local machine, which was developed using WAMP server. I tried moving it over to a webost, and i keep getting this message in my pages -

Error -

```
<b>Warning</b>:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /www/host.com/appi/htdocs/connect.php:11) in <b>/www/host.com/appi/htdocs/session-public.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br /> 
<br /> 
<b>Warning</b>:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /www/host.com/appi/htdocs/connect.php:11) in <b>/www/host.com/appi/htdocs/session-public.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
```

I have a session start to be set if not already set, in all my pages.
My question is, if it works in my local machine, why this error when the same code is moved over to a shared web server online?

Comment: The reason is mentioned in the error message: “headers already sent”.

Comment: You can't send any output before starting the session.  Gumbo explains below why you get away with it on your local machine, but you really should fix the actual problem rather than working around it with output buffering.  Stop sending any output before the session; that includes whitespace (look for a gap before the starting `<?php` in your scripts).

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a lot of [configuration options](http://php.net/ini.list) that allow you to configure PHP from outside of a running script. One of them is [*output_buffering*](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) that allows you to implicitly buffer any output before sending it to the client.

If output buffering is enabled, you can modify the HTTP header even after some output as the output is buffered and not immediately sent to the client that would implicate sending of the HTTP header before.

So it seems that your local machine has *output_buffering* enabled while your other server hasn’t.

Comment: But the OP should note that output buffering is only a workaround (in this case; there are performance reasons in some situations) to the real bug in the OPs code - that it's sending output before it tries to start the session.

Comment: stack wont let me answer my own question right now, but well i have solved the issue.. so here is the ANSWER - well, the problem as to why it was working fine in my local machine server (wamp), and why it suddenly stopped working when the same code was moved online to a web host was because of the encoding issues between linux (web host) and windows (my machine server). REFERENCE - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

so solution is to run notepad ++ and change the encoding to "utf w/o bom", save and retest. it worked for me. thanks everyone for your help. ciao!